# What is the closest mysql type for s3 key?

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3

My system uses s3 and I need to also store metadata for each file in a mysql table - specifically the key name.

What type should I use in mysql to most closely resemble the limitations on s3 keys?

More exactly, my column type should be able to store anything s3 can use as its key and nothing more.

Comment: Is the key anything other than just a string? So use a VARCHAR of the appropriate length.

Comment: I'm also looking for encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link in the S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) an object key is a sequence of unicode characters who's UTF-8 encoding is at most 1024 bytes.  So a VARCHAR of length 1024 with UTF-8 encoding should do the trick.

Comment: Because UTF-8 stores different characters with different number of bytes, VARCHAR(1024) could store much more than the allowed 1024 bytes? So following your instruction I would be able to store more than what's in an s3 key, but it's my best option considering I don't know which characters will be stored?

Comment: @lf215 I believe so, yes (for both of your questions)